# ERROR: COPY escape must be a single one-byte character (multi-delimiter appears to work on Postgres 9.0 but does not on Postgres 9.2)

Tags: java, postgresql, talend

I have a Talend enterprise job that loads data into a PostgreSQL database via the `COPY` command. When migrating to a new server this command fails with the following error message: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:ERROR: COPY escape must be a single one-byte character`

The thing is, I looked over the documentation for both Postgres 9.0 and 9.2. Both documentations say that multi-byte delimiters are not allowed. So I'm very confused on why this job works perfectly on Postgres 9.0 but not on 9.2.

I am unable to edit this Talend job, as it's very old and we do not have the source code for the job anymore. I am unable to see what the actual delimiter is. I am also unable to see exactly how the `COPY` command is being run, such as whether it's pushing directly to the server via the Postgres driver, or if it's created a temporary CSV file somewhere and then loading the data into the server. I believe the reason we have multi byte delimiters setup is due to the use of various special characters in a few of the columns for multiple tables.

I am not aware of any edits to the source code of the old 9.0 Postgres server.

The reason we are migrating servers is due to the end of life for CentOS 5. The new server runs CentOS 7. I believe that both servers are using the default Postgres versions that come in the default CentOS repositories. I know for sure that the CentOS 7 server is indeed running the default Postgres version, as I installed it myself through `yum`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, is there a way to copy the old Postgres server, dependencies, and executables to our new server, in case the source was modified?

Comment: Can you see the query that is running in pg_stat_activity?  That should help figure out what the delimiter is, which may help narrow down the issue.

Comment: That error message was already present in PostgreSQL 9.0, so the version change cannot be the problem. Don't use PostgreSQL 9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. Apparently there is a bug with the version of Talend we are using and the Postgres driver included.

The only solution is to install Postgres 9.0 on our CentOS 7 machine by downloading the source and compiling against CentOS 7 libraries.

The bug can be found here: [Talend Bug](https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-22604)

Comment: it's always a good idea to install postgresql directly from the sources. The JDBC would have problems with PG 11 if talend is not configured to use 9.x database.